# Why is noexcept a problem for boost spirit semantic action in c++17?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, c++17, boost-spirit-qi

following code gives me weird compiler error on VS2019 with c++17 mode:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

class Duration
{
  std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano> d;

public:
  void addHours(uint64_t val) noexcept
  {
  }
};


int main()
{
  Duration d;
  namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
  namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
  qi::int_parser<int64_t, 10> int64_;
  std::string s = "2h";
  boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, Duration()> durationRule = (int64_ >> "h")[phoenix::bind(&Duration::addHours, qi::_val, qi::_1)];

  boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), durationRule, boost::spirit::ascii::space, d);
}
```

If I compile it with c++14 mode all is fine, but with c++17 or c++20 it fails. I found that the problem is the noexcept keyword behind the addHours method. Can anybody explain why this is a problem?

Comment: "_...following code gives me weird compiler error..."_ care to share ?

Answer (score 1):

The Phoenix library predates noexcept.

Since c++17 [*The noexcept-specification is a part of the function type and may appear as part of any function declarator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#:%7E:text=The%20noexcept-specification%20is%20a%20part%20of%20the%20function%20type%20and%20may%20appear%20as%20part%20of%20any%20function%20declarator).

The implication is that you run into limitations of Phoenix when using the noexcept specifications in c++17 mode.

Specifically, the thing that appears to break is return type deduction: *Functions differing only in their exception specification cannot be overloaded (just like the return type, exception specification is part of function type, but not part of the function signature) (since C++17).*

### Improvements

In your case, since you're using C++17, why not simplify the whole thing? **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6da0d930f5f26d03)**

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, Duration()> durationRule //
    = qi::eps[_val = 0s]                                       //
    >> (qi::int_ >> "h")[_val += _1 * 1h];
```

The output

```
"2m" -> failed
"3h" -> 10800
"4s" -> failed
```

gives away my intent!

### Bonus Extension 1: units

Using a simple table like

```
qi::symbols<char, Duration> unit_;
unit_.add
    ("ns", 1ns) ("nano", 1ns)
    ("us", 1us) ("μs", 1us) ("micro", 1us)
    ("ms", 1ms) ("milli", 1ms)
    ("s", 1s)
    ("m", 1min) ("min", 1min)
    ("h", 1h) ("hour", 1h)
    ("d", 24h) ("day", 24h)
    ;
```

Now with the trivial change of

```
    >> +(qi::int_ >> unit_)[_val += _1 * _2];
```

It does evaluates a boatload of interesting sequences: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64e2ca6c34350a04)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::nano>;
namespace qi   = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    using namespace qi::labels; // _val, _1 etc

    qi::symbols<char, Duration> unit_;
    unit_.add
        ("ns", 1ns) ("nano", 1ns)
        ("us", 1us) ("μs", 1us) ("micro", 1us)
        ("ms", 1ms) ("milli", 1ms)
        ("s", 1s)
        ("m", 1min) ("min", 1min)
        ("h", 1h) ("hour", 1h)
        ("d", 24h) ("day", 24h)
        ;

    qi::int_parser<int64_t, 10> int64_;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, Duration(), qi::blank_type>
        durationRule         //
        = qi::eps[_val = 0s] //
        >> +(int64_ >> unit_)[_val += _1 * _2];

    for (std::string const s :
         {
             "2m",
             "3h",
             "4s",
             "1ms -1ns",
             "1 day -23h",
             "3600000000ns",
             "1 day -23h -50m +3600000000ns",
         }) //
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s);

        Duration d{};
        if (phrase_parse(                //
                s.begin(), s.end(),      //
                durationRule >> qi::eoi, //
                qi::blank, d))
            std::cout << " -> " << d / 1.0s << "s\n";
        else
            std::cout << " -> failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"2m" -> 120s
"3h" -> 10800s
"4s" -> 4s
"1ms -1ns" -> 0.000999999s
"1 day -23h" -> 3600s
"3600000000ns" -> 3.6s
"1 day -23h -50m +3600000000ns" -> 603.6s
```

Note I've shifted some details around to make it work. Notably `qi::eoi` to check the entire input is consumed, and declaring the skipper in the rule (`blank` instead of `space` to exclude newlines). Without that, the rule was implicitly lexeme anyways ([Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

Comment: As you can probably see from the heading in my answer, I was planning to add another version. Here's the Spirit X3 version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66c68cfb3d1a146e

Comment: I found two cases that don't work, but I also don't know why: "200µs" and "1m2ms". The first contaisn the special char, the secons runs into an ambiguity of m and ms I guess.

Comment: Haha that's the difference between [U+00B5 MICRO SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm) and [U+03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm). I didn't know about the first one :) And the second one JustWorks™ for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01812161a11f5019 (perhaps you changed the `symbols<>` to branches? In that case, you have to mind the order of the branches. `symbols<>` automatically matches the longest possible match from the trie)

Comment: Noticed that X3 requries switching the encoding for that character to be accepted: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e125ca79750d8951